# D3 4.0 rangeRoundBands equivalent?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I see a lot of D3 code that has something like this:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
```

As of D3 version 4.0 `d3.scale.ordinal()` is now `d3.scaleOrdinal` and `rangeRoundBands` seems to be gone.

```
> d3.scaleOrdinal()

{ 
  [Function: scale]
  domain: [Function],
  range: [Function],
  unknown: [Function],
  copy: [Function] 
}
```

What would the D3 v4 equivalent of this code (from Mike Bostock's [bar chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)) be?

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In D3 4.x `rangeRoundBands` was moved to the new *Band* scale:

```
d3.scaleBand()
    .range([range])
    .round([round]);
```

That's equivalent to:

```
d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([range]);
```

Here is the API: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band-scales

Comment: So the replacement is `var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width])` in the end. Thanks!

Comment: you know, i really think it was a bad idea they  made breaking it all up. it just makes everything harder!

Comment: From the docs I would agree with the answer - but I cannot explain the following:
```y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, 3], 0.2);
y.rangeBand()``` 

returns 12 in the console, but using d3 7 the following:

```y = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, 3]).padding(0.2);
y.bandwidth()``` 

returns 2. I'd expect the results to be the same??

Answer (score 73):

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
```

The above calculates bands and sets padding between band. In v4, the equivalent is

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.1);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),

margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.txt", function(d) {
  d.y = +d.y;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
```

A launchable syntax for a classic chart using both scaleBand and scaleLinear.