# Ordinal Scales and RangeRoundBands in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, range, scale

I am trying to create a bar chart with scales using D3.js

The chart works fine with linear scales but I can't get it to work with ordinal scales. The range for ordinal scale is not getting computed correctly.

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: d3.scaleOrdinal(...).domain(...).rangeRoundBands is not a function

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bar Graph</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bar{
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 2px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25, 27, 29, 5, 32];
            var w = window.innerWidth;
            var h = window.innerHeight;
            var linearScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0, w]);
            var ordinalScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                           .domain(d3.range(data.length))
                           .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
            var svg = d3.select("body")     //create the canvas
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);
            var bar = svg.selectAll("rect")
                         .data(data)
                         .enter()
                         .append("rect")      //create rect element
                         .attr("class", "bar")
                         .attr("x", function(d, i){return ordinalScale(i)})
                         .attr("y", function(d){return (10 * Math.max.apply(null, data)) - (8 * d);})  //set co-ordinates
                         .attr("width", function(d){return ordinalScale(d)})
                         .attr("height", function(d){return 8 * d;})
                         .attr("fill", function(d){
                            return 'rgb('+d*2 + ',' + d*4 + ',' + d*8 + ')';
                         });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: I have also tried rangeBands but get the same error and range returns discrete values(the start and end points).
Also, I'm using d3v4.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37548699/5768908

Comment: Thanks a lot @GerardoFurtado Works like a charm